# Some questions about derivation of uncertainty principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics* by Griffiths and Schroeter, they derive the Uncertainty principle in the following way:

First, they define
$$f=\left(\hat A-\langle A\rangle\right)|\Psi\rangle$$
$$g=\left(\hat B-\langle B\rangle\right)|\Psi\rangle$$

Where $\hat A, \hat B$ are two Hermitian Operators.

Then they use the definition of standard deviation and Schwarz inequality to show that

$$(\sigma_A\sigma_B)^2\geq\vert\langle f\vert g\rangle\vert^2 \tag{1} $$

Now since in general $\langle f\vert g\rangle$ is complex, they define $z=\langle f\vert g\rangle$ and use the fact that
$$\vert z\vert^2\geq [Im(z)]^2=[(z-z^*)/2i]^2\tag{2}$$

Thus

$$(\sigma_A\sigma_B)^2\geq \left[\frac 1{2i}\left(\langle f\vert g\rangle -\langle g\vert f\rangle\right) \right]\tag{3}$$

Question 1: Since we are interested in the minimum possible value of $\sigma_A\sigma_B$ wouldn't it make more sense to talk about (1) rather than (3)? After all, the limit put on $\sigma_A\sigma_B$ by (1) is greater than (3).

Question 2: To me, it seems arbitrary, at this stage, to use $\vert z\vert^2\geq [Im(z)]^2$ in (2), when one could've just used $\vert z\vert^2\geq [Re(z)]^2$. So what's the rationale to choose imaginary over real?

Comment: ...which definition of the standard deviation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is true that by taking step (2) we are 'unnecessarily' making the uncertainty principle weaker. Furthermore, it's possible to use $|z|^2=Re(z)^2+Im(z)^2$ to derive the stronger [Robertson-Schrödinger uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Mathematical_formalism):
$$\sigma_A^2\sigma_B^2\geq \left|\frac{1}{2}\langle \{ \hat{A},\hat{B}\}\rangle-\langle \hat{A} \rangle \langle \hat{B} \rangle \right|^2 + \left|\frac{1}{2i}\langle[\hat{A},\hat{B}]\rangle \right|^2 $$
And of course, leaving out the first term, we get the well-known uncertainty principle (3):
$$\sigma_A^2\sigma_B^2\geq \left|\frac{1}{2i}\langle[\hat{A},\hat{B}]\rangle \right|^2 $$
So why do we generally see the latter over the former? It's largely a matter of practicality. Note that the expected value of any operator $\hat{O}$ is $\langle \hat{O} \rangle=\langle\psi|\hat{O}|\psi\rangle$, which is dependent on the state $|\psi \rangle$. Thus, $\langle \{ \hat{A},\hat{B}\}\rangle$, $\langle \hat{A} \rangle$ and $\langle \hat{B} \rangle$ are generally not known. On the other hand, there are many cases where  $\langle[\hat{A},\hat{B}]\rangle$ is either the same regardless of $|\psi\rangle$, such as:
$$\langle[\hat{x},\hat{p}]\rangle=\langle i\hbar \hat{I} \rangle = i\hbar \Longrightarrow \sigma_x\sigma_p\geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$$
or otherwise noteworthy, such as:
$$\langle[\hat{L_x},\hat{L_y}]\rangle=\langle i\hbar \hat{L_z} \rangle\Longrightarrow \sigma_{L_x}\sigma_{L_y}\geq \left|\frac{\hbar}{2}\langle L_z \rangle\right|$$
and:
$$\langle[\hat{O},\hat{H}]\rangle=i\hbar \frac{d\langle\hat{O}\rangle}{dt} \Longrightarrow \frac{\sigma_{O}}{\left|\frac{d\langle\hat{O}\rangle}{dt}\right|}\sigma_{H}\geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$$

At the end of the day, the uncertainty principle has little utility for doing exact calculations (if you have $|\psi\rangle$ you can just explicitly calculate $\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_B$), but it does provide some insight into the relationship between the observables of a system. In that regard, the term $\left|\frac{1}{2}\langle \{ \hat{A},\hat{B}\}\rangle-\langle \hat{A} \rangle \langle \hat{B} \rangle \right|^2$ simply isn't very useful and is therefore left out.